# JQuery DataTable HideColumn

Tags: java, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTable plugin in Java Struts application for list data screen. Where I added show/hide column facility of datatable to user. Also some of the column has text input for update details in a list.
But when I'm submitting the form when user needs to update the list. Action Class will get called. And in the action class I'm able to get the table data but data has only visible columns data not hidden columns. And for business validation I need hide columns as well.

Actually when I hide the columns which is not available in the DOM as well

Can anybody suggest me what would be the solution for it.

Comment: Please post relavant code ...

Comment: Answers probably in that plugins docs

Answer (score 0):

you can use following function for Hide column:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
} );
} );

function fnShowHide( iCol )
{
/* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object    */
 var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

Or YOu can do this using `fnDrawCallback` like:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
 "fnDrawCallback": function () {
     //Hide Column 1
     $("#example tbody tr td:nth-child(1)").css("display", "none");
     $("#example thead tr th:nth-child(1)").css("display", "none");            
 }
 } );
```